# Kafka consumer/producer API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

How do count that how many total messages have been sent to the topic in Kafka and how many have been consumed or committed by the consumer at that time?

I am initiatting kafka connector as-

```
Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("mytopic");

JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = 
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
   String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, 
   kafkaParams, topics);
```

And processing as -

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
 System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
        + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
 rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record._2));
});
```

For 2 seconds

```
--- New RDD with 2 partitions and 3 records
value-1
value-0
value-2
--- New RDD with 2 partitions and 7 records
value-3
value-5
value-7
value-9
value-4
value-6
value-8
--- New RDD with 2 partitions and 8 records
value-11
value-10
value-13
...
```